# How can i avoid ConcurrentModificationException in below scenario

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice, completable-future

I the below scenario, I can get the ConcurrentModificationException while calling `dslList.clear();`
How can I avoid concurrent modification exception without hampering the performance?

```
public void processFiles(List<FileIdBothDirectoryInformation> files) {
        AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30);
        List dslList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<CompletableFuture<Void>> completableFutures = files.stream().map(file -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        
            try {
                File localFile = nasDataLoader.downloadFile(file.getFilePath());
                if(localFile != null) {
                    List<> lines = parse(localFile);
                    dslList.addAll(lines.stream().map(line -> {
                        apply(line);
                        return new Xxx(line);
                    }).collect(Collectors.toList()));
                   
                    if(dslList.size() >= BATCH_SIZE || count.incrementAndGet() == files.size()) {
                        persistenceManager.persist(dslList);
                         dslList.clear();
                    }
                }
            } catch () {
                                
            } 
        }, executorService)).collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<Void> result = completableFutures.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(Collectors.toList());
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
```

Comment: `ArrayList` is not thread-safe, and the logic of your code does not make any attempt at handling thread safety. In it’s current form, even with a thread-safe list implementation, the same batch could be sent multiple times to the persistence manager. It needs to be completely rewritten to work as, I suppose, is intended.

Comment: @DidierL - How can I stop sending 'same batch multiple times to the persistence manager' Could you please point out the issues/suggestions?

Comment: Multiple threads might check the list size and try to persist & clear it simultaneously. You would need to either add synchronization over that block, or maybe work with a blocking queue and a parallel thread that processes it.